# Transform a column included in array column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to transform an array column in my dataframe, array is called 'cities' and has the type Array(City) and I want put city name in upper case.

Structure:

```
val cities: StructField = StructField("cities", ArrayType(CityType), nullable = true)

def CityType: StructType =
    StructType(
      Seq(
        StructField(code, StringType, nullable = true),
        StructField(name, StringType, nullable = true)
      )
)
```

Code I tried:

```
   .withColumn(
      newColumn,
      forall(
        col(cities),
        (col: Column) =>
          struct(
            Array(
              col(code),
              upper(col(name))
            ): _*
          )
      )
    )
```

Error says

> cannot resolve 'forall(...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing called `forall`. You can use `transform` instead:

```
// sample data
val df = spark.sql("select array(struct('1' as code, 'abc' as name), struct('2' as code, 'def' as name)) cities")

import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "newcol", 
    transform(
        col("cities"), 
        (c: Column) => struct(c("code"), upper(c("name")))
    )
)

df2.show
+--------------------+--------------------+
|              cities|              newcol|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[[1, abc], [2, def]]|[[1, ABC], [2, DEF]]|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```